# Issues about fade color in fill p5.js

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

since few days i'm stuck on a problem.

I start to introduce myself, I'm Quentin, french student, i also work for onepoint .

My problem is that i am on a personal project, learn processing and WebGL later, i want use fade in my triangle, a dynamic fade with two specific color ( the first is the start color and the second the endColor ). I use lerpColor but my code doesn't work and i would like have some help please ! :) ( sorry, my english is better when i talk )

That's my whole code :

```
let x = 50;
let x1 = 100;
let y = 150;
let speed = 5;
let startColor;
let endColor;
let amt;


function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, 800);
    
}

function draw() {
    colorMode(RGB);
    background(252, 238, 10);
    shape(); // Appel de la function shape
    bounce();// appel de la fonction bounce

}

function bounce() {
    x = x + speed;
    x1 = x1 + speed;
    y = y + speed;
    if (y > windowWidth || x < 0) {
        speed = speed * -1;
    }
}

function shape() {
    colorMode(HSB, 360, 100 , 100);
    triangle(x, 200, x1, 100, y, 200);
    noStroke();
    let startColor = color(288 , 71 , 60 );
    let endColor = color( 352 , 90 , 16);
    amt += 0.01;
    let colorTransition = (lerpColor(startColor,endColor,amt));
    if (amt >= 1){
        amt = 0.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes your help was precious i found how to make the effect i want with the color and now i'm thinking of a method to move my triangle randomly on the canvas and duplicate this triangle :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`fill()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/fill) to set the fill color:

```js
noStroke();
fill(colorTransition);
triangle(x, 200, x1, 100, y, 200);
```

```js
let x = 0, x1 = 100, y = 200, speed = 0, amt = 0;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, 800);
    
}

function draw() {
    colorMode(RGB);
    background(252, 238, 10);
    shape(); // Appel de la function shape
    bounce();// appel de la fonction bounce

}

function bounce() {
    x = x + speed;
    x1 = x1 + speed;
    y = y + speed;
    if (y > windowWidth || x < 0) {
        speed = speed * -1;
    }
}

function shape() {
    colorMode(HSB, 360, 100 , 100);
    let startColor = color(288 , 71 , 60 );
    let endColor = color( 352 , 90 , 16);
    amt += 0.01;
    let colorTransition = (lerpColor(startColor,endColor,amt));
    if (amt >= 1){
        amt = 0.0;
    }

    noStroke();
    fill(colorTransition);
    triangle(x, 200, x1, 100, y, 200);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ! Have a nice day ! :)